# Kotlin and Jack unsupported (Android Studio 2.3.2)

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I am getting this error while configuring kotlin plugin with Jack. I an using Android studio 2.3.2 currently.

> *Error:Kotlin Gradle plugin does not support the deprecated Jack toolchain. Disable Jack or revert to Kotlin Gradle plugin version
>   1.1.1.*

Comment: Jack is deprecated, you shouldn't use it

Comment: Don't use deprecated tools for your safety

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using latest IDE(3.0, preview version) it won't let you use `Jack` or you are using kotlin version above 1.1.1.

Jack has been deprecated because of the build time performance issue, It was mentioned in one of the session of google IO 2017. You can read this [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html)

In official documentation of Jack following warning is given:

> The Jack toolchain is deprecated, as per this [announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html). However, you may continue to use it to enable Java 8 language features until the replacement is available.

If you still want to use it, switch back you Android studio IDE to 2.3, and revert back to kotlin 1.1.1

**EDIT**

Kotlin by default supports Lambda expressions. If you want to use lambda expression in java with Kotlin also, you have to use Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: Yes i am using 2.3.2 . So how do i enable lambda expression along with kotlin in IDE 2.3.2 ? Is this possible?

Comment: which gradle dependency are you using?

Comment: I am using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

Comment: Yes you can not use jack with Kotlin version above 1.1.1. set your kotlin version 1.1.1. It will work.

Comment: By any means if i want to use latest kotlin version with lambda expression what might be the best solution?

Comment: Kotlin by default supports lambda expression. You do not need to do anything. Just enable kotlin and you are done.

Comment: But i am using both kotlin and Java Class . So i think the best solution is to download Android Studio 3.0 preview?

Comment: Can you please update you answer and specify more clearly about the context so that i can upvote you answer. 1. Only Kotlin class (No need of Lambda Expression kotlin itself supports it) and 2. If you want both kotlin and java support utilizing latest kotlin plugin then you need to download android studio 3.0 preview.

Comment: Yes, but you might find hard to use kotlin in 3.0, because i tried it on ubuntu machine but kotlin lint functionality wan't working. You can try if it works for you.

Comment: Yes i am also using ubuntu machine . Thank you for the suggestion i will check it out.