# Android - Not able to add jar created in java8 with kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I addded jar which require,

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

which require jack to support java8.

According to latest kotlin plugin gives, Error:Kotlin Gradle plugin does not support the deprecated Jack toolchain.
Disable Jack or revert to Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.1.1.

Currently not able recreate jar with java7. And need use latest version of kotlin which has deprecated Jack toolchain.

I check all possible ways in app.gradle.

Not able to solve this by preview version of studio 3.0 according to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/index.html#new_android_profiler).

[image]

project level gradle file,

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app level gradle file,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.root.trial"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/bel-1.0.jar')
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use android gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha9?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin and Jack unsupported (Android Studio 2.3.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105504/kotlin-and-jack-unsupported-android-studio-2-3-2)

Comment: @Stas that gives solution to use kotlin version below 1.1.1, but in my case need to use latest one.

Comment: @DeKaNszn gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha9 not worked.

Comment: Use latest android sutudio 3.0.0-alpha6 or later along with corresponding gradle version. Then you just need to add source and target compatibility no other config is needed like Jack.

Comment: @paril you can not use `jack` with `Kotlin` version above `1.1.1`

Comment: if i change version belov 1.1.1 for kotlin, gives... Error:Cannot cast object 'task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'' with class 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask_Decorated' to class 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.AbstractCompile'

Comment: @paril that was an issue in `1.0.7` version of kotlin. you need to check `1.1.1`, it's a latest version with `jack` support

Comment: i changed kotlin version to 1.1.1  which gives below error, Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:transformKotlinClassesWithJillForDebug'.
> File '/home/parita/Android/StudioProjects/Trial/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug.jar' specified for property 'inputJarFile' does not exist.

Comment: @chandil03 i used android studio 3.0 canary 9 for same project but not works.

Comment: post your both gradle file: project and app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not updated gradle plugin in build.gradle(:project).

Replace you project level gradle file with following:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.